# Explanation on several iterations of an increment?

Tags: java, for-loop, increment

We had this assignment on one of our tests last week.
My answer was "k" (incrementing letters 2 times for 5 iterations).
When I run this in intelliJ, I get "c".
The teacher tells us it's "h".
I feel utterly lost. Would anyone mind explaining it to me? Thank you!

```
    public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            char a = 'a';
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) ;
            a++;
            ++a;

            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: look at the `;` after the for-statement and then think about what's contained in the loop's body.

Comment: a++ = b, ++a = c hence you see c. If you remove semicolon, then you would get h in the output.

Comment: This should actually print ``c`` since the increments are not inside the loop.

Comment: Unless teacher has a different code snippet, he's wrong. It's `'c'` as mentioned by many.

Answer (score 4):

Let's see (line by line) what's going on:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     char a = 'a';                  // <- start from 'a' 
     for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) ; // <- trick: the loop does nothing: please notice ";"
     a++;                           // <- increment : 'a' + 1 = 'b'
     ++a;                           // <- increment : 'b' + 1 = 'c'

     System.out.println(a);         // print out: ('c')
  }
```

So you have `'c'`. Your teacher, propably, suggested the code below (please, notice the *only difference*: abscence of `;` after *for loop*):

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      char a = 'a';                 // <- starts from  'a' 

      for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)  // <- six times... 
      a++;                          // <- increment: 'a' + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 'g'  

      ++a;                          // <- increment: 'g' + 1 = 'h' 

      System.out.println(a);        // print out ('h')
   }
```

Your understanding

> incrementing letters **2** times for **5** iterations

should be implemented as

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     char a = 'a';                 // <- starts from  'a' 

     for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)   // <- five times... (please, notice < instead of <= ) 
     {                             // do two increments in a loop
     a++;                          // <- first increment  
     ++a;                          // <- second increment 
     }

     System.out.println(a);        // print out ('k')
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The assignment did state ">=", and did not have curly brackets. May I ask what makes adding curly brackets give a different result?

Comment: @Vantalim: *for loop* executes just one operation; by adding `{}` we organize several operations (`a++;`  and `++a;` in your case) into one

Comment: Bingo! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

The `;` at the end of this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) ;
```

...means the loop does nothing. The null statement is attached to it.

Consequently, `a` is incremented twice, which is why you get `'c'` when you run it.

**Without** the `;` at the end of that line, the `a++` on the next line would be inside the loop, so `a` would be incremented 6 times by the loop (once for `i == 0`, again for `i == 1`, and so on up to and including `i == 5`), to `'g'`, and then again after the loop (`++a`) to `h`.

Comment: Thank you so much! With the exception of clearly failing at spotting the basic mistake I made, this made it clearer. So am I understanding it right that the counter in a for-loop is incremented after the loop has ran once?

Comment: @Vantalim: Yes. A `for` loop has four parts: *Initialization*, *test*, *increment*, and *body*. It runs like this: 1. Do *initialization*; 2. Do *test*, exit loop if result is false; 3. Do *body*; 4. Do *increment*; 5. Go to Step 2.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is terminated by the `;`. This makes the `for` loop completely irrelevant and has no effect.

The rest is just 2 increments making `a` to `c`

Comment: Thank you, I should have spotted this! I'm quite new, so I clearly need some more detail-training!

Answer (score 0):

If the instructor is telling you the answer is 'h' then you may have miss copied the code.  To get 'h' it should be:

```
public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
          char a = 'a';
          for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) 
            a++;
          ++a;  
          System.out.println(a);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right; both with me miss copying the code, and the code you suggested.